# A function in a module i imported returns with not defined

Tags: python, import, module

```
    import mafia

game.add_faction(Town())
game.add_faction(Town())
game.add_faction(Mafia("Crypto Mafia"))
game.add_player("Alice", Cop(town))
game.add_player("Bob", Doctor(town))
game.add_player("Eve", Goon(mafia))
```

Hello I'm trying to write a python program with a module called mafia (It's from github: https://github.com/calder/mafia/) But when i tried to test the module it gives me "Game" is not defined, I installed the mafia, checked it with dir command, it works. I'm the faulty one here so please enlighten me.

(Btw don't bash me i'm new to python)

Edit: changed import mafia to 
`from mafia import *`

now gives 'mafia.game' has no attribute 'add_faction' error.

Comment: If you take a close look at the sample code of that module, you'll notice that `import mafia` is different from `from mafia import *`.

Comment: Now it gives 'mafia.game' has no attribute 'add_faction' error.

Comment: @ÜmitYayla have you created game instance as Game() object?

Comment: If you copy the example given - https://github.com/calder/mafia#usage - does that work??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add following line.

```
from mafia import *

g = Game()
```

Then you can append your code

```
game.add_faction(Town())
game.add_faction(Mafia("Crypto Mafia"))
game.add_player("Alice", Cop(town))
game.add_player("Bob", Doctor(town))

game.add_player("Eve", Goon(mafia))
```